# Convert sql query to Ecto query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a sql query as follows

```
select username, email, nickname, lastname, firstname, phone 
 from a
 where NOT EXISTS
 (
 select b.tip_team_id from b
 where b.season_id = 1
 and b.round_id = 2
 and a.id = b.user_id
 );
```

I want to convert it into Ecto query… Can some one help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried anything and got stuck somewhere? Do you have an Ecto [Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html) for that table?

Answer (score 0):

You can run raw SQL queries by using the underlying [adapter](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.html), e.g.

```
query = """
  select username, email, nickname, lastname, firstname, phone 
  from a
  where NOT EXISTS
  (
    select b.tip_team_id from b
    where b.season_id = $1::integer
    and b.round_id = $2::integer
    and a.id = b.user_id
  )
"""

Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(MyApp.Repo, query, [1, 2])
```

Note that the `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/3` function will take a list of ordered arguments to substitute into your query (so that the first item in the list substitutes for the `$1` in the query, the second for `$2`, etc).  In order for this to work, you need to pass your defined [Ecto.Repo](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#content) module where you specified `use Ecto.Repo` and your database engine (`MyApp.Repo` in the example above).  Also note that you can omit the `::integer` suffix if the value you are substituting is not an integer.

The result returned will be a `%Postgrex.Result{}` struct, e.g.

```
%Postgrex.Result{
   columns: ["username", "email", "nickname", "lastname", "firstname", "phone"],
   command: :select,
   connection_id: 327,
   messages: [],
   num_rows: 1,
   rows: [["admin", "admin@email", "Big Guy", "Jones", "Boss", "888-555-1212"]]
 }
```

So you'll have to do some pattern-matching to grab the list of `rows` from that struct.

Sometimes it's easier to simply use raw queries like this rather than spending the time to define Ecto Schema modules -- it's really up to you and your use cases, but depending on the situation and your preferences, you may wish to do this in the more "standard" way of defining Ecto schemas for each table in your database.